# Is it possible for a local Java server to interact with global client

Tags: java, websocket, client-server

My question is can I have a local Java server (running with tomcat or Jetty), and a global client. What I mean is if my website is on a domain and has an address of www.example.com then can my local server interact with the client (which is www.example.com). (The local Java server would be running on the computer only).

I know it's possible to have a local server and a local client, but what about a local server and global client?

**multi-stage server-client architecture:**
[image]

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with `global client`? A front-end for your web-application which is running on your local tomcat or jetty?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355. Yes that's what I mean

Comment: So this would be an example of a distributed application (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing). The question below about efficiency depends on your application: If your webserver would run out of resources (RAM or CPU usage e.g.) with your application, it would be a consideration to deploy the application on your local system with more resources. Matter then, that every traffic which is done by the users of your application must pass the way from your domain to your local system. What you need to figure out is a compromise between the resources of the Hardware and the network traffic.

Comment: edited the post such that it might become clearer. Reject it if it doesn't fit your claims

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355. What do you mean by network traffic. If the server is local then how would there be any traffic between the global client and local server. (Just for clarification, I expect this local server to be on many different computers).

Comment: There is something called Server-Client-architecture. I think you just switch the both terms `server´ and `client´. You have to research for distributed applications and clarify or bring examples of what you really want to have

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355. To clarify this is what I am doing. Whenever a user performs a particular action, a JavaScript function is triggered. Now the data needs to be passed from the JavaScrip to my Java class because that's where I am processing the data. Next, I have to send back the data to the JavaScript which will display that on the screen (on the website). Depending on if I make a local server to communicate with the global client or global server to communicate with a global client, my actions change. So based in this what do you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but there are couple things that can get in your way:

- You'll probably have no domain address for your server, so you will have to connect using IP instead of DNS name
- If your server is in a local network (behind router, typically using IP address starting `192.168.*.*` or `10.*.*.*` if IPv4), you will need to set up the router to [forward a port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) to your server

  - You'll then need to use the router's external address and port to connect to your server
- Make sure no firewall on the way is blocking the traffic

Comment: thank you. Is it more efficient to just make a global server? I am a bit confused.